# How to force a time limit for recording webrtc audio

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, audio, webrtc

How can I force a time limit for recording an audio file using webrtc audio in firefox/chrome?

Example:  A user comes to a website and I want them to record their voice for 7 seconds only, then have them email it to me.

Comment: Could you not just set a timeout that will kill it if it is not killed already? Also, what are you using to capture the audio to a file/blob?

Comment: @Benjamin Trent At the moment I'm just going to have it go to a file and want the user to email it to me as an attachment

Comment: Well, whenever a user requests a recording to start, just create a timeout that calls the recorder to end after 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Option 'timeSlice' is a way to time limit recording.
It would be help follow example:

```js
function captureMicrophone(callback) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false 
    }).then(function(microphone) {
     callback(microphone);
    }).catch(function(error) {
     log(error);
    });
}

var blobs = [];
var audio = document.querySelector('audio');
captureMicrophone(function(microphone) {
    setSrcObject(microphone, audio);
 audio.play();    
    
 recorder = RecordRTC(microphone, {      
  recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder,
  mimeType: 'audio/wav',
  desiredSampRate: 16000,
  numberOfAudioChannels: 1,
  timeSlice: 50, // pass this parameter
  // getNativeBlob: true,
  ondataavailable: function(blob) {
   blobs.push(blob);
   var size = 0;
   blobs.forEach(function(b) {
    size += b.size;
   }); 
   /////      
  }
 });    
    
 recorder.startRecording();
 recorder.microphone = microphone;
    
 document.getElementById("start").disabled = true;
 document.getElementById("stop").disabled = false;
});
```